# Is there any algorithm to decide whether a series with integral coefficiens is a algebraic function?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, power-series

Given a series with integral coefficiens as following:
$$F(x)=\sum_0^i a_i x^i,\text{where }a_i\in \mathbb{N}\bigcup 0 $$$$\text{and there is a computable function $\psi$ such that } \forall  i  \psi(i) =a_i$$
Is there any algorithm to decide whether such a series is a algebraic function?

Comment: The input to an algorithm has to be a finite amount of data.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch,yes.So we have to put some restriction on $a_i$,let me make some modification of the question.

Comment: See http://eudml.org/doc/87381 for the ${\bf F}_p[X]$ version, subsequently enlarged by Denef and Lipshitz.

Comment: @NAME_IN_CAPS,thank you very much,I have just search for the two authors' article,the titles seem to focus on my questions.

Comment: I'm not quite sure my references are all that relevant, as the $F_p(X)$ case is quite different from the integer case I suspect, but it is true that the characteristic $p$ (and $p$-adic) versions are closely related to automata. Another paper in this genre is Kedlaya's "Finite automata and algebraic extensions of function fields"

Comment: @NAME_IN_CAPS,yes,and when I read one of the articles,I have found that I know some result of the paper. Thank you very much.

Comment: Very sorry, a similar question had been asked by me in May 11, I have completely forgotten the post of May 11 which appears in right column of the above post. And I have just thought about the question in another light, that is poles, branch points and natural boundary. but let's not close or delete the post, since we are expecting positive cases and have not gotten a complete list of positive cases

Comment: An answer has to be there is no such algorithm. But if the series is transcendental, we can find it is, otherwise we may have no algorithm by which  to find that it is algebraic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are given a Turing machine and an input to it, define $a_i$ as follows. First $a_i=0$ if $i$ is not a power of $3$. If the Turing machine hasn't halted after $n$ steps set $a_{3^n} = 1$ otherwise if it halts set $a_{3^j}=0, j \ge n$. These coefficients are the values of a computable function. As the series $\sum_0^{\infty} x^{3^n}$ is transcendental, having an algorithm that for all such data determines whether the resulting series is algebraic or not is equivalent to solving the Halting problem, which is known to be unsolvable.

Comment: Anyway,it is interesting to link the question to halting problem in such a way, but I think it is very subtle to link them.

Comment: Intuitively,there may be some gap in the argument.